# Необходима помощь в создании таблицы в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Есть таблица "Заявки", появилась необходимость создать "стадии выполнения" для каждой заявки.
- Взаимодействие происходить должно так: человек открыл заявку, получил
  информацию выполнил действия (подготовил документы, произвел расчеты и
  тд), после этого отметил во вкладке "стадии заявки" те пункты, что
  выполнили рядом с этим пунктом, указалось именно его имя (допустим).
- Стадии у всех заявок идентичные по названию. Если что-то непонятно,
  пишите.

Мой вариант создать таблицу с полями:

- id_стадии
- id_заявки
- id_sub-пункта1
- sub-пункт1_имя_изменившего_статус
- id_sub-пункта2
- sub-пункт2_имя_изменившего_статус
- id_sub-пункта3
- sub-пункт3_имя_изменившего_статус
- ...и тд

Вопрос задаю, потому что этот мой вариант получается слишком извращенным, на мой взгляд. Вдруг подскажут что-то более нормальное.

Comment: Вот это - "если что то непонятно, пишите" - к кому относится?

Comment: Вы должны создать исчерпывающую таблицу-словарь стадий, и ввести в таблицу заявок дополнительное поле атрибута-стадии и другие, связанные с этим атрибутом, поля (исполнитель, штамп времени и пр.).

Comment: @Akina Может я не понял или не правильно выразился. Одну заявку могут вести несколько человек, то есть все стадии в этой заявке могут быть отмеченны разными людьми  и необходимо зафиксирвоать кто. таблица-словарь имелось ввиду (номер название всех 56 пунктов)?
(у меня проблема представить как связать таблицы эти )

Comment: Тогда у Вас стадия заявки - это вообще отдельная сущность, и храниться должна она в отдельной таблице, связанной с таблицей заявок N:1. И именно в таблице стадий и должны появиться поля, связанные с этапами исполнения.

Comment: @Akina не повлияет ли это на скорость? если будет такая куча таблиц?

Comment: Любое изменение влияет на скорость. Однако работа с БД по текущему описанию - чисто интерактивная, а при ней скорость работы далеко не самая большая проблема.

Comment: А что за субпунткты такие ? Это некие отдельные сущности к заявке ? Тогда у них должны быть свои id, а раз так то таблица которая хранит стадии выполнения превращается в id-субпункта, id-стадии, кто менял

Comment: @Mike опять же я наверное ввел в заблуждение, по сути я себе так представляю к примеру. Глобальный-> Грузоперевозка.  sub-пункт1->Загрузка. sub-пункт2->Выгрузка. возможно глобальный пункт нет необходимости хранить бд. допустим может на основе того выделены ли все sub-пункты просто средствами js выделять Глобальный (надеюсь понятно написал)

Comment: @Vadim Все равно не особо ясно. возможно это у вас дерево. но суть хранения стадий от этого не меняется. Если вам хочется в одну запись рядом положить несколько суб-пунктов и соответствующие им имена меняющих то вам нужно несколько записей, в каждой из которых только один суб-пункт и соответствующее ему одно имя изменившего. Это называется _1я нормальная форма_ https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: @Mike я правильно вас понял? вот пример таблиц только не сообразил куда деть тех кто отметил стадию
[ссылка](http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/170419/3wu688674W.jpg)  (делал в [этом редакторе](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/)  )

Comment: Уже не так, начиная с таблицы "заявки". эта таблица делится на две: в "Заявки" только id, имя компании и описание. во второй таблице записи со структурой: id-заявки, id-глобальной стадии. Если нужна нумерация стадий, то третье поле "номер стадии". Аналогично в стадиях никаких суб-стадий, а в таблице sub-стадии ссылка на глобальную стадию к которой она относится

Comment: @Mike аа я понял, как то я все наоборот сделал. а как же быть с присвоением того кто отметку на sub-стадии поставил?

Comment: По хорошему для этого к заявке должна фиксироваться не стадия, а суб-стадия и тогда в этой записи как раз кто ее поставил

Comment: @Mike В принципе размышляя я к этому ж пришел. спасибо большое за отклик! получилось вот так:
[ссылка](http://www.picshare.ru/view/8047376/)